# Split data from one cell into multiple cells

Tags: excel, split, vba

I have a file containing names and dates together.

Example:

```
Jane Hoffen30. october 2014 v 19:31 UTC+01      
Lenka Copper30. october 2014 v 19:31 UTC+01
```

I need to **split name and dates into two cells**, something like this:

```
Jane Hoffen    -----     30. october 2014 v 19:31 UTC+01        
Lenka Copper   -----     30. october 2014 v 19:31 UTC+01
```

alternatively three cells

```
Jane Hoffen   ------      30. october 2014  -----      19:31    
Lenka Copper  ------      30. october 2014  -----      19:31
```

I tried to create some macro but nothing worked.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Showing the code, even if it doesn't work, helps others understand better what you are trying to accomplish. It also allows them to see where you are going wrong and give valuable VBA hints.

Comment: You should experiment with the *text-to-columns* feature on the data tab of the ribbon

Answer (score 0):

try this the code below and adapt it to your needs. It goes through all cells in column A and searches the position for the first number that appears in the cells content. Afterwards, the left part up to the position is put in column B and the rest in column C.

```
Sub split()
Dim n As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim EndOfNamePos As Integer
Dim SrcText As String
Dim TrgName As String
Dim TrgDate As String

    For n = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

        SrcText = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1).Value

        'Find first Number in the Source Column
        For m = 1 To Len(SrcText)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(SrcText, m, 1)) = True Then
                EndOfNamePos = m
                Exit For
            End If

        Next m

        TrgName = Left(SrcText, EndOfNamePos - 1)
        TrgDate = Right(SrcText, Len(SrcText) - EndOfNamePos + 1)

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 2).Value = TrgName
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 3).Value = TrgDate

        TrgName = ""
        TrgDate = ""
        SrcText = ""
    Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for using `RegEx` (Regular Expressions). This requires minimal looping

```
Public Sub SeparateStringWithRegEx()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim Match, Matches
    Dim c

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    ' Change this to your range
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "^\D+"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        Set Match = RegEx.Execute(c)
        c.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(Match(0))
        c.Offset(0, 2) = Trim(Replace(c, Match(0), ""))
    Next c
End Sub
```